# ColdFusion : Create Date Time with UTC

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to use a UTC time, so that the user can get the time of things at their UTC, rather than the server.

I am currently setting the time with this : which works.

```
<cfset stime = (DateFormat( sdate, "yyyy-mm-dd" ) & " " & "#hr#:#mn# #HH#") />
```

I need to add the UTC Stamp of say -8.0 (PST).

```
(timeFormat(stime, "hh:mm:ss, Z"));
```

With Z being a default setting of `UTC` which I have.

How do I create the combined Date and Time to insert into database with the UTC.

Comment: Coldfusion's DateConvert function was made for this very situation.

Comment: There's some terminology confusion making this question unclear.  UTC is [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).  It is the same for everyone on the planet.  There's no such thing as "their UTC rather than the server".  They would both be the same.   "UTC Stamp of say -8.0 (PST)" also doesn't make any sense.  Perhaps you are asking about a specific *offset* from UTC for a particular time zone?

Comment: If you are trying to save this on a DB, you might want to look up its date functions. On newer version of SQL Server, they have at least six functions to get things like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#GetSystemDateandTimeValues

Comment: Perhaps I'm overthinking. I guess what I'm trying to do is if a client has an event at say 2pm PST (-8.0 UTC), how do I prevent the server from showing it as 2pm MST when the ColdFusion would use the server time.

Comment: I would store the date/time in UTC, so that it is non-location-specific. Then store an offset for the event. Then display that stored UTC time converted with the event's offset. The event would have to know it's offset (or it be calculated) when it is saved, but then the event could be moved to a new location in a different offset, then all that would need updated would be the offset. You'd probably also want to keep track of Daylight Savings.

Comment: I have the UTC DateCovert from below working and inserting fine... Now trick is to show the availability etc.  Would I work off the UTC then?

Comment: Your database doesn't care where the user is. In my opinion, it's better to store datetimes in a single, universal format so that it doesn't matter where your users are nor where your database server gets relocated to somewhere down the road. UTC time will be UTC time, no matter where it is. You don't even have to store an offset. It can be calculated from wherever your user needs to call it from. Than you just apply that offset to your database value, and you know what the local time will be.

Comment: Also note the definitions of the time that you're using. A datetime value isn't really `21 October 2019 12:00:00 pm` or `2019-10-19T120000.000` or anything recognizable as a date. It's usually some long number (`1571677200`) that represents seconds or milliseconds from the systems epoch (1970-01-01 or 1900-01-01 or 1899-12-31 or whatever, essentially `0`). And in a situation like this, you may be dealing with multiple definitions of epoch, ie your CF application may use 1 epoch, your database another, your JavaScript another. So you want to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a local date to UTC in ColdFusion or Lucee:

```
utcNow = dateConvert("Local2UTC", now())
```

To insert it as a value in a database:

```
queryExecute(sql="
    insert into tablename (
        utcDate
    ) values (
        :utcNow
    )
    ",
    params=[
        {name="utcNow", value=utcNow, cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"}
    ],
    options={
        datasource: dsn,
        result: "local.insertResult"
    }
);
```

Comment: utcNow = dateConvert("Local2UTC", now()) is working. I am setting the UTCTime<cfset utctime = dateConvert("Local2UTC", stime)>
 <cfset utcact = #DateAdd("h", #set.utc#, utctime)#> What I found is I can not use the time difference of just UTC to Client, but the difference of the server to the Client.  But I can not get this cfif working <cfif utctime LTE utcadmintime> when doing a convert <cfset utcadmintime = #DateAdd("h", -set.admhr, chk.utcact)#>

Comment: utcNow = dateConvert("Local2UTC", now()) : I worked on difference of server time vs client UTC time, ie: Alberta vs BC, it is UTC 8 hrs... But only 1 hr difference off server time.  But now having cfif utc time issues

Comment: This only deals with converting to utc on the server. The way I deal with client (browser) timestamp display is to use a js library (like sugarjs or moment.js) to display the utc timestamp sent to the browser from the server. I typically send the client a iso8601 timestamp string.