# ColdFusion : CreateDateTime : 13 digit epoch time

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Is there an easy way to create ColdFusion now() into a 13 digit UTC Epoch Time

I found this code... But it shows a -1343911774836
I know I can force positive, but I don't even know if the conversion is correct.

```
<cfset startDate = createdatetime(#now()#)> 
<cfset datetimeNow = dateConvert( "local2Utc", now() )>
<cfset UnixStamp = datediff( 's', startdate, datetimeNow )>
<b>#unixstamp#</b>
```

This works from RRK Comments

```
<cfset startDate = now()> 
<cfset datetimeNow = dateConvert( "local2Utc", now() )>
<cfoutput>
  <b>#now().getTime()#</b>
  <b>#datetimeNow.getTime()#</b>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Here is one of your previous questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466809/coldfusion-create-date-time-with-utc.

Comment: You can do `now().getTime()`. [Example](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=87d29f9d-e657-4d5f-97ab-6195d99101fa/930b5426-4aae-450a-a4cb-4c7e5786fc8f/ba5cbabb-9936-440e-a12a-82df27d9b0ae.cfm)

Comment: FYI - A Unix Epoch is the number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970, in UTC (not since `startDate`). If you do a search on CF and Unix Epoch, there's lots of examples on this, such as https://cflib.org/udf/GetEpochTime

Comment: Excellent rrk - works. Dan the other one is for something completely different that I can use on virtual servers when converting UTC Time from a Server Time.

Comment: Its for the KuCoin API "KC-API-TIMESTAMP" - its working. So maybe just a 13 digit unix timestamp.  I've never used it before.  Now just need to sort out the "KC-API-SIGN".

Comment: `getTime()` works well, but fwiw it's actually a [java method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the java [`getTime()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) linked to date variables in Coldfusion.

```
now().getTime()
```

[Example](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=87d29f9d-e657-4d5f-97ab-6195d99101fa/930b5426-4aae-450a-a4cb-4c7e5786fc8f/ba5cbabb-9936-440e-a12a-82df27d9b0ae.cfm)